# Should I use 'Volatile' in following case?

Tags: c, volatile

Consider that I have multiple '.c' source files in my application.

> Module1.c

```
static char status_variable = 0;

Modify1() 
{

   status_variable = 'a';

}

Modify2() 
{

   status_variable = 'x';

}

char GetStatus()
{
   return status_variable;
}
```

The function `Modify` can be called from other .c files based on events(Not through ISR's)

> Module2.C

```
TakeAction()
 {
    if(GetStatus() == 'a')
    {
        //do something
    }
    else 
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Now my question is do I need to declare `status_variable` as `volatile` in this case?

EDIT1:

My Application 16-bit micro-controller(RL78) ,I am not using any operating system.

EDIT2:

As some have commented,multi-threading was not at all in my mind.I have wrote down a simple non-preemptive round-robin scheduler for my application. I have no idea about multi-threading environment and what makes the variable to be volatile in that case.How it is different from my environment?If some one could elaborate it more then  it would be a great help.

Comment: @Mat No I am not using any OS.and no threads involved.

Comment: Then no, you don't need to make it volatile.  Volatile would help if the "variable" was somehow mapped over memory used by an I/O device, and it would be needed if you somehow interrupted the running program and jumped to other code where you wanted to see earlier changes (but that'd be a form of non-concurrent threading, or some interrupt processing which you've said isn't happening).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `status_variable` is not bound to any:

- Memory-mapped peripheral registers
- Global variables modified by an interrupt service routine
- Global variables within a multi-threaded application

You are safe to skip `volatile` keyword in the `status_variable` declaration.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate point 3 more. Is multi-threading same as multitasking in RTOS ?

Comment: @Vagish: in a multi-threaded application you use globals for sharing data between threads (there is no MMU-based memory protection), whereas when speaking about OS processes/tasks you generally never share data between tasks through globals (the per-process memory address spaces could be clearly separated by MMU). In the last case you use some form of IPC (inter-process communication) mechanism. So, volatile is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use volatile if the modules can be run simultaneously as said by @BlueMoon93(if there is no other locking mechanism for threads). But if these modules are to run one after the other then you can safely skip the usage of volatile.